# Hierarchy predictive top down approach

Tags: time-series, forecasting, multilevel-analysis

I'm having a problem with using a hierarchical top down forecasting approach. According to my understanding, when I split an aggregated value on the levels below it, I have to know the percentages regarding how the levels below compose the top.

For example, my hierarchy is composed as follows:
Merchandise group -> merchandise sub group -> SKUs

My question is: it is possible to forecast the number of SKUs composing the new merchandise sub group, and is this percentage in the forecasting hierarchy top down approach?

Do you think that it makes sense?

Comment: I suggest you read https://www.otexts.org/fpp/9/4

Comment: Hi Rob. Thank you for your anwer. The last think that I have to figure out is if the forecasted proportion shoul be generated using a time serie or there is another approach  to follow. Thank you in advance.